# Reading from a properties file Spring 3

Tags: spring, annotations

I've tried looking for an example of using the @Value annotation in Spring 3 to read values from a properties file using Spring EL but I haven't found a good example.

Here are some of the constituent pieces I've seen to achieve this except I don't know how all of these work together to read from a properties file

```
<util:properties id="ewConfiguration" location="classpath:ew.properties"/>
```

Now, how do I use this in my class to retrieve values from the ew.properties file to bind them to instance variables ?

For instance, if there exists a property 
url=www.google.com

and I have

```
@Configuration 
class AppConfig {

 @Value("???")
 private String url //what do I use in the place of the ??? to bind the value of the url property 
                    // in the properties file to this instance variable ?
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[This example](http://chrislovecnm.com/2010/03/08/spring-3-java-based-configuration-with-value/) should be enough to get you started.

**Nutshell** Reference the property file's values like this:

```
@Value("#{ewConfiguration['url']}")
private String url;
```

Comment: url gives 502 bad gateway now